# Generic factory of generic containers

Tags: java, generics, factory-pattern

I have a generic abstract class `Factory<T>` with a method `createBoxedInstance()` which returns instances of `T` created by implementations of `createInstance()` wrapped in the generic container `Box<T>`.

```
abstract class Factory<T> {
    abstract T createInstance();

    public final Box<T> createBoxedInstance() {
        return new Box<T>(createInstance());
    }

    public final class Box<T> {
        public final T content;

        public Box(T content) {
            this.content = content;
        }
    }
}
```

At some points I need a container of type `Box<S>` where `S` is an ancestor of `T`. Is it possible to make `createBoxedInstance()` itself generic so that it will return instances of `Box<S>` where `S` is chosen by the caller? Sadly, defining the function as follows does not work as a type parameter cannot be *declared* using the **super** keyword, only *used*.

```
public final <S super T> Box<S> createBoxedInstance() {
    return new Box<S>(createInstance());
}
```

The only alternative I see, is to make all places that need an instance of `Box<S>` accept `Box<? extends S>` which makes the container's content member assignable to `S`.

Is there some way around this without re-boxing the instances of `T` into containers of type `Box<S>`? (I know I could just cast the `Box<T>` to a `Box<S>` but I would feel very, *very* guilty.)

Comment: Have you tried abstract class Factory<T, S super T> and then use T only createInstance(), while using S everywhere else? Or maybe abstract class Factory<T extends S, S> ?

Comment: If you want a `Box<S>` why wouldn't use use a `Factory<S>` The problem you have is that even if S extends T you can't know a `Factoy<T>` creates a boxed S, it could be a boxed U (which also extends T)

Comment: @Luis The problem with that is that I have to decide up front what type I want to use for S. The idea is that I can create a Factory of T and then use it to create boxed T's with varying type parameters for S.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey The factory creating a U where U extends T is fine. But in my example I want T to extend S, not the other way round. If I wanted S to extend T in `createBoxedInstance` I'd just write `<S extends T>` in front of the declaration.

Comment: I think that what you have is a common problem in Java that there is no clean exit. For instance if you have a List<String> a and you want to assign it to List<CharSequence>  b. You can't, because they are fundamentally different types even though String implements CharSequence. If it worked, and you tried to add a CharSequence to b that is not a String, somebody could try to get it from a and you would have a type violation down the road.

Comment: @Luis Thank you for the explanation. I'm aware that `List<T>` and `List<S>` are not related regarding the type system, even when `S` and `T` are. I have now accepted and embraced the fact that declaring a type as `List<? extends X>` is possible for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rewriting your *other* code to not use `Box<S>` but instead uses `Box<? extends S>`, so it will accept a `Box<T>`, too. This way, you make it explicit that the Box may also contain subclasses of `S`.

The following should also work, if you make your Box `static`:

```
public static <S, T extends S> Box<S> createBoxedInstance(Factory<T> factory) {
  return new Box<S>(factory.createInstance());
}
```

However, it may be unable to do type inference for `S`, at which point you need:

```
public static <S, T extends S> Box<S> createBoxedInstance(Factory<T> factory, S dummy) {
  return new Box<S>(factory.createInstance());
}
```

Another variation that is very explict:

```
public static <S, T extends S> Box<? extends S> createBoxedInstance(Test<T> factory, S dummy) {
  return factory.createBoxedInstance(); // Actually a Box<T>
}
```

Comment: These are all hacks however - you don't get clean semantics from this. It is much more sensible to use `Box<? extends S>` to acknowledge the box may be for a subtype.

Comment: This answer contains the most examples that answer my original question even though I'm accepting it because of it's advice to not actually want a function that converts a `Box<T>` to a `Box<S>` internally. `Box<? extends T>` is the way to go. Look at [Ben Schulz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8280336/402281) if you actually want a solution to my original question, using an unchecked cast internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive what you want to some degree:

```
public final <S extends Box<? super T>> S createBoxedInstance() {
    // sadly we can't capture the wildcard in the bound of S
    // this means we have to cast, but at least it's local..
    // *should* this cast ever break due to reification, we
    // can fix it here and be good to go
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    S box = (S) new Box<T>(createInstance());
    return box;
}

Factory<Integer> factory = getFactory();
Box<Number> box1 = factory.createBoxedInstance();
Box<Object> box2 = factory.createBoxedInstance();
```

I do think that your own `Box<? extends S>`-Alternative is the correct approach. However, if this will force client code to be littered with wildcards, the above *might* be preferable.

Comment: I've linked your answer in the comments of the accepted answer, but I have come to agree to the your advice (and others') to go with `Box<? extends S>`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot do it (or you have to use strange conversions) is the following
Imagine that the Box content instead of being final also had a setter. Also, let's assume the type S is the super type of both R and T. The following code would be valid without any casting.

```
Box<T> boxT = new Box<T>(objectT);
Box<S> boxS = boxT;
S objectR = new R();
boxS.set(objectR);
```

That code would be valid with no warnings, except the setter would fail at runtime with an unexpected exception (unexpected in the sense that it is not obvious that a casting exception can be thrown) because you cannot assign something with a of type R to something of type T.

You can read more at http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic3 (but have aspirin nearby, you will get a headache)

As many people said, probably using box in the other code is the best option.